# How the partition be invariant if the correlator not invariant under global conformal transformation?

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory, mathematics

Under the global conformal transformation

$$\tau \rightarrow \frac{a\cdot \tau +b }{c\cdot \tau + d}, ad-bc=1, a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z} $$

the partition function is invariant

$$Z(\tau,\bar \tau)= Z( \frac{a\cdot \tau +b }{c\cdot \tau + d},  \frac{a\cdot \bar \tau +b }{c\cdot \bar \tau + d}, )$$

However, for a simple case of $\tau \rightarrow a\cdot \tau$, all the coordinates on the torus were scaled up, $z\rightarrow a\cdot z$, the correlator

$$\langle \phi_1(z_1,\bar z_1) \phi_2(z_2,\bar z_2)\rangle
=
a^{h_1/d} a^{\bar h_1/d} a^{h_2/d} a^{\bar h_2/d}
\langle \phi_1(a\cdot z_1,a\cdot \bar z_1) \phi_2(a\cdot z_2,a\cdot \bar z_2)\rangle$$

However, partition function is a sum of states
$$\int D\phi e^{-S_E(\phi)} 
= Tr e^{-2\pi Im \tau H } e^{iP (2\pi Re \tau)}
$$
and, (this is the part I wasn't quite sure) in radial quantization
$$
??=\langle 0| \sum_{\text{all possible }\phi }\phi_1(z_1) \phi_2(z_2)... e^{-2\pi Im \tau H }   |\infty \rangle
$$
Since the correlator may be changed(even non linearly), I don't see why the partition function can stay invariant.

How the partition be invariant if the correlator not invariant under global conformal transformation?(I saw some paper mentioned the Jacobian but that did not explain the correlators.)

Comment: $\tau \to a \tau$ is not an $SL(2,{\mathbb Z})$ transformation, unless $a=1$ (which is the trivial transformation).

Comment: @Prahar That's correct. Let's use it as a trivial example without making the equations too messy.

Comment: Not sure why you would do that. It's not a trivial example, it's just incorrect. The statement is that it is invariant under $\tau \to \tau + 1$ and $\tau \to - 1/\tau$ (all others are obtained from these). This is the invariance you need to check.

Comment: @Prahar $a=d=1, b=c=0$, it;'s an element of the group. I thought if the lattice parameter $\tau$ was transferred, all the $z_i$s were transferred the same. I don't quite understand how all the correlator could change but the partition function, the sum of all possible states, did not.

Comment: $a=d=1$ and $b=c=0$ corresponds to $\tau \to \tau$. That is no transformation at all. So of course, the partition function is invariant in this case. There is nothing to check.