# Is 2d CFT partition function invariant under $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ or $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory

In Applied Conformal Field Theory by Paul Ginsparg page 8,

> the globally defined infinitesimal generators $\{l_{-1},l_0,l_1\}
> \cup
> \{\bar l_{-1},\bar l_0,\bar l_1\}$ resulted the finite form of the transformation
> $$z\rightarrow \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, \bar z\rightarrow  \frac{\bar a \bar z+\bar b}{\bar c\bar z+\bar d}$$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}$ and $ad-bc=1$, the group $SL(2,\mathbb{C})/\mathbb{Z}_2\approx SO(3,1)$

In Conformal Field Theory by A.N. Schellekens Eq. 5.7

> the partition function is invariant under the modular group
> $$\tau \rightarrow \frac{a\tau +b}{c\tau +d}, a,b,c,d,\in\mathbb{Z}; ab-bc=1$$
> the group is $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}_2$

Why the global conformal transformation in 2d was $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ on the plane but $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ on torus(lattice parameter)?
Is 2d CFT partition function invariant under $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ or $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/798341/2451

Comment: $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ transformations acting on co-ordinates are symmetries of a CFT in flat space. If you want that CFT to be consistent on a torus, the additional requirement is that the partition function (which does not depend on co-ordinates) stays invariant after an $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ transformation acts on the complex structure.